# Traveling Salesman with GA, mutation, crossover

Tags: python, algorithm

For school last semester, I wrote a python program to solve the traveling salesman problem. For those not familiar with what it is, the wolfram alpha explanation does a pretty good job of explaining it.

This was one of the first programs I wrote in Python, and so far I LOVE the language, coming from a C++/Java background. Anyway, I used a lot of inefficient methods/programming practices to get it working, so I wanted to go back and improve. I used a genetic algorithm with mutations and ordered crossovers. First, I create a list of random unique nodes with a given length and a given number of strategies. The GA runs through a given number of generations of these strategies, changing a random selection of strategies by using ordered crossover and an inverse mutation between two random indices. Each strategy has a given probability of a mutation and another probability of crossover. After this, the algorithm chooses two strategies at random, takes the best one, then compares it to the best solution found so far. The end goal of the program is to find the shortest distance through all the nodes.

[Here is my original, inefficient, working code](http://pastebin.com/zkTiKjRd)

Here is my newer, efficient, not working code:

```
import random
import math
import pprint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def create_nodes(num_nodes, num_rows):
    elements = range(1, num_nodes + 1)
    return [random.sample(elements, num_nodes) for _ in range(num_rows)]

def mutate(table, node_table, mutate_probability, cross_probability):
    for next_id, row in enumerate(table, 1):
        nodes = len(row)
        # print
        # print "Original: ", row
        #mutation
        if random.random() > mutate_probability:
            mini, maxi = sorted(random.sample(range(nodes),2))
            row[mini:maxi+1] = row[mini:maxi+1][::-1]
            # print "After mutation: ", row
            # print "Between: ", mini, maxi

        #crossover
        if random.random() > cross_probability:
            try:
                next_row = table[next_id]
                # print "Parent: ", next_row
            except IndexError:
                pass
            else:
                half_length = nodes//2
                mini = random.randint(0, half_length)
                maxi = mini + half_length - 1 + (nodes % 2)

                crossed = [None] * nodes
                # print "Before crossed: ", row
                crossed[mini:maxi+1] = next_row[mini:maxi+1]
                # print "Cross with: ", crossed
                iterator = 0
                for element in row:
                    if element in crossed:
                        continue
                    while mini <= iterator <= maxi:
                        iterator += 1
                    crossed[iterator] = element
                    iterator += 1
                row[:] = crossed
                # print "After crossed: ", row
                # print "Between: ", mini, maxi
def sample_best(table, node_table):
    t1, t2 = random.sample(table[1:], 2)
    return distance(t1, t2, node_table)

def distance(s1, s2, node_table):
    distance1 = sum_distances(s1, node_table)
    distance2 = sum_distances(s2, node_table)

    if distance1 < distance2:
        return s1, distance1
    else:
        return s2, distance2

def sum_distances(strategy, node_table):
    dist = 0
    first_row, second_row = node_table

    for idx_next_node, node1 in enumerate(strategy, 1):
        try:
            node2 = strategy[idx_next_node]
        except IndexError:
            node2 = strategy[0]
        dist += math.hypot(
            first_row[node2-1] - first_row[node1-1],
            second_row[node2-1] - second_row[node1-1])

    return dist

def draw_graph(node_table, strategy):
    graphX = [node_table[0][index - 1] for index in strategy]
    graphY = [node_table[1][index - 1] for index in strategy]

    plt.scatter(graphX, graphY)
    plt.plot(graphX, graphY)
    plt.show()


def main(nodes=8, strategies=100, generations=10000, mutateP=.7, crossP=.7):
    #create node locations
    node_table = create_nodes(nodes, 2)
    # for i in range(2):
    #   print node_table[i]

    #create first generation
    table = create_nodes(nodes, strategies)
    # for i in range(strategies):
    #   print i
    #   print table[i]

    print "TOP MEN are looking through:"
    print strategies, "strategies in", generations, "generations with",
    print nodes, "nodes in each strategy..."

    best_score = None
    for count in range(generations):
        mutate(table, node_table, mutateP, crossP)
        # crossover(table, node_table, crossP)
        strategy, score = sample_best(table, node_table)

        if best_score is None or score < best_score:
            best_strategy = strategy
            best_score = score

        if count % 100 == 0:
            print "Foraged", count, "berries"
            print "Best we got so far:", best_score, "with: ", best_strategy

        # if count % 2 == 0:
        #   print count
        #   for i in range(strategies):
        #       print table[i]



    print "=========================================================================="
    print "Best we could find: ", best_score, "for strategy", best_strategy

    draw_graph(node_table, best_strategy)

main()
```

The new code is what I'm having trouble with. The mutation and crossover seem to be working correctly, but the algorithm isn't even coming close to finding a solution and I have no idea why. Thanks for the help in advance, I really appreciate it!

Comment: what is the objective function?